# Android: Is it possible to interact with/update an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

AsyncTask's are mostly presented as a solution to running well-defined computations or tasks. The classic example is a downloader as an AsyncTask which is fed a URL, updates its progress to the UI, and exits when completed. Is there a reasonable (not-too-hacky) way to add/change input to the AsyncTask while it's running? Perhaps setting up a queue of items that the AsyncTask has to process and then altering that queue from the main application...? Would that 'break' the AsyncTask model for example?

Comment: a commonly accepted way would be to create a new asynctask for each new item to process. using a custom executor, your tasks can be serialized, too, making it look quite like a queue

Comment: You might want to check the `IntentService` class if you want to perform one task after another

Comment: +1 to  @Matt Quiros.  Spawning multiple long-running async tasks is not recommended.  Moreover, the behavior may be different on different OS versions.  Services or just threads/handlers and the like seem to be a better choice in your case.

Comment: what is your task doing so that you want to update its input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. AsyncTask is a thread that has already buited in communication mechanisms to the UI thread. However this communication is only from `AsyncTask` to `UI` and not in the reverse direction as you need.

Also, the maximum number of simultaneous `AsyncTask` in Android is 1 in several API versions.

To implement thread safe communication from `UI` to `AsyncTask` you will need to use `Handler` or `BlockingQueue` classes.

Personally, I wouldn't do it. I would use directly a `Thread` with a `Handler` or `BlockingQueue`.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simply do it by getting a object in the doInBackground() metheod from a synchronized collection that is managed by your activity.